Unable to invoke Task module in MS Teams botbuilder bot
I'm facing an issue while trying to invoke a task module in Microsoft Teams. I have created an adaptive card with a button defined as follows:
"actions": [{
    "type": "Action.Submit",
    "title": "Test Fetch",
    "data": {
        "msteams": {
            "type": "task/fetch"
        },
        "data": "toto"
    }
}]

When I click the button, the on_teams_task_module_fetch() method is triggered. In this method, I return a TaskModuleTaskInfo object like this:
class TaskModuleResponseFactory:
    @staticmethod
    def create_response(value: Union[str, TaskModuleTaskInfo]) -> TaskModuleResponse:
        if isinstance(value, TaskModuleTaskInfo):
            return TaskModuleResponse(task=TaskModuleContinueResponse(value=value))
        return TaskModuleResponse(task=TaskModuleMessageResponse(value=value))

    @staticmethod
    def to_task_module_response(task_info: TaskModuleTaskInfo):
        return TaskModuleResponseFactory.create_response(task_info)

async def on_teams_task_module_fetch(self, turn_context: TurnContext, task_module_request: TaskModuleRequest):
    task_info = TaskModuleTaskInfo(
        width=900,
        height=900,
        title="Super Title",
        url="https://app.random-coffee.com",
        fallback_url="https://app.random-coffee.com",
    )
    return TaskModuleResponseFactory.to_task_module_response(task_info)

Despite this setup, I'm encountering an error in the popup when interacting with the bot in the conversation.
Error Details:
The error appears in the popup window after clicking the button on the adaptive card.
The task module does not seem to load as expected.
Steps Taken So Far:

Verified the button action type and data in the adaptive card.
Ensured the on_teams_task_module_fetch() method is invoked correctly.
Checked the TaskModuleTaskInfo parameters for accuracy (width, height, title, URL).

Request for Help:
Could anyone provide insights on how to troubleshoot and fix this issue? Is there something I'm missing in the setup or response handling?
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Are you still having an issue with this? If so, check that you have the Team's app manifest correctly configured for using a task module. Also, double check that you have your bot's bot id entered into the appropriate parameters and/or that it matches that of the bot you are using. You can also try running this Team's task module sample, updating only the bits needed to make it run. If successful, compare it to yours and make any necessary changes.
